# Can I change a value in parent page's JS from iframe's JS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent

I have a page with 3 iframes and this page loads a JS file that has

```
var stayFifty = new Boolean(false);
```

and a function that changes what it does based on this boolean.

In an iframe on this page I have an onclick function defined as

```
toggleFifty = function() {
    parent.stayFifty = new Boolean(!(stayFifty.valueOf()));
};
```

added to an img tag with

```
onclick="toggleFifty();"
```

But when I click on the img tag, the toggleFifty function doesn't seem to fire. I believe this has something to do with how the toggleFifty function is trying to change the stayFifty variable. Can someone explain how to fix this issue and a little bit about the scope problem?

I tried using information from [this link](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/?page=7) but it seems I am not understanding something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `parent` when you change the value of the `stayFifty` variable:

```
toggleFifty = function() {
    parent.stayFifty = !parent.stayFifty;
};
```

BTW, notice that you don't need to use Boolean constructor when working with boolean variables, and when you declare you can simply use [Boolean literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals#Boolean_Literals):

```
// on your parent page
var stayFifty = false;
```

Comment: Thanks much. The Boolean constructors were a leftover of trying to get it to work and not knowing where to go. Can't believe that I forgot to reuse the parent.stayFifty.